# Use nftables to set up IPv6 NAT to IPv4

Tags: nat, ipv6, ipv4, nftables

I am working on setting up a number of EC2 instances with IPv6-only networking.

A few of these servers require occasional access to IPv4-only resources controlled by third-parties.

Amazon has a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/let-your-ipv6-only-workloads-connect-to-ipv4-services/) from February 2022 about using NAT Gateway for this. I don't want to pay $$$ for the "NAT Gateway" that will be rarely used, so I wanted to set up my own NAT gateway running on a `t4g.nano` instance. Amazon has [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#create-nat-ami) about how to do this as well, which uses `iptables` commands on an instance running Amazon Linux.

We have all of our servers running Ubuntu, and my boss does not want us to bring in a different package management system he has to learn, so we would like to use Ubuntu 22.04 to set up NAT. Ubuntu 22.04 ships with `nftables`, and I would like to use that.

I found several guides for nftables NAT online, but none of them mention IPv6.

Putting bits and pieces together from those guides, I ended up with this:

1. Set `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` and `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1` in `sysctl.conf` (actually in `/etc/sysctl.d/forwarding.conf`)
2. Create dual-stack NAT rules

   ```
   nft add table inet nat
   nft 'add chain inet nat postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100 ; }'
   nft add rule inet nat postrouting oifname ens5 masquerade
   nft 'add chain inet nat prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority -100 ; }'
   # Debug output on
   nft add rule inet nat prerouting meta nftrace set 1
   nft add rule inet nat postrouting meta nftrace set 1
   ```
3. Verify rules exist (`nft list table inet nat`)

   ```
   table inet nat {
           chain postrouting {
                   type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                   oifname "ens5" masquerade
                   meta nftrace set 1
           }

           chain prerouting {
                   type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                   meta nftrace set 1
           }
   }
   ```
4. Generate some traffic on an IPv6-only machine

   ```
   curl -vv http://ip4only.me/api/
   *   Trying 64:ff9b::4275:27c9:80...
   *   Trying 66.117.39.201:80...
   * Immediate connect fail for 66.117.39.201: Network is unreachable
   ```
5. Use `tcpdump` and `nft monitor` to verify that the traffic to the DNS64-encoded address is reaching this machine

   ```
   # tcpdump -i ens5 -n port 80
   tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
   listening on ens5, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
   05:10:52.348952 IP6 2600:1f18:xxxx:xxxx:b428:1047:7d73:9484.55882 > 64:ff9b::4275:27c9.80: Flags [S], seq 2015291953, win 62587, options [mss 8941,sackOK,TS val 3259538098 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   05:10:52.349007 IP6 2600:1f18:xxxx:xxxx:36b0:5593:30bc:2d87.55882 > 64:ff9b::4275:27c9.80: Flags [S], seq 2015291953, win 62587, options [mss 8941,sackOK,TS val 3259538098 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   05:10:53.357529 IP6 2600:1f18:xxxx:xxxx:b428:1047:7d73:9484.55882 > 64:ff9b::4275:27c9.80: Flags [S], seq 2015291953, win 62587, options [mss 8941,sackOK,TS val 3259539107 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   05:10:53.357566 IP6 2600:1f18:xxxx:xxxx:36b0:5593:30bc:2d87.55882 > 64:ff9b::4275:27c9.80: Flags [S], seq 2015291953, win 62587, options [mss 8941,sackOK,TS val 3259539107 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   05:10:55.373514 IP6 2600:1f18:xxxx:xxxx:b428:1047:7d73:9484.55882 > 64:ff9b::4275:27c9.80: Flags [S], seq 2015291953, win 62587, options [mss 8941,sackOK,TS val 3259541123 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   05:10:55.373549 IP6 2600:1f18:xxxx:xxxx:36b0:5593:30bc:2d87.55882 > 64:ff9b::4275:27c9.80: Flags [S], seq 2015291953, win 62587, options [mss 8941,sackOK,TS val 3259541123 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   ```

   ```
   # nft monitor trace
   trace id 3b90a155 inet nat prerouting packet: iif "ens5" ether saddr 12:57:f4:30:c4:2e ether daddr 12:b3:8b:26:a9:f1 ip6 saddr 2600:1f18:xxxx:xxxx:b428:1047:7d73:9484 ip6 daddr 64:ff9b::4275:27c9 ip6 dscp cs0 ip6 ecn not-ect ip6 hoplimit 64 ip6 flowlabel 702875 ip6 nexthdr tcp ip6 length 40 tcp sport 42834 tcp dport 80 tcp flags == syn tcp window 62587
   trace id 3b90a155 inet nat prerouting rule meta nftrace set 1 (verdict continue)
   trace id 3b90a155 inet nat prerouting verdict continue
   trace id 3b90a155 inet nat prerouting policy accept
   trace id 3b90a155 inet filter forward packet: iif "ens5" oif "ens5" ether saddr 12:57:f4:30:c4:2e ether daddr 12:b3:8b:26:a9:f1 ip6 saddr 2600:1f18:xxxx:xxxx:b428:1047:7d73:9484 ip6 daddr 64:ff9b::4275:27c9 ip6 dscp cs0 ip6 ecn not-ect ip6 hoplimit 63 ip6 flowlabel 702875 ip6 nexthdr tcp ip6 length 40 tcp sport 42834 tcp dport 80 tcp flags == syn tcp window 62587
   trace id 3b90a155 inet filter forward verdict continue
   trace id 3b90a155 inet filter forward policy accept
   trace id 3b90a155 inet nat postrouting packet: iif "ens5" oif "ens5" ether saddr 12:57:f4:30:c4:2e ether daddr 12:b3:8b:26:a9:f1 ip6 saddr 2600:1f18:xxxx:xxxx:b428:1047:7d73:9484 ip6 daddr 64:ff9b::4275:27c9 ip6 dscp cs0 ip6 ecn not-ect ip6 hoplimit 63 ip6 flowlabel 702875 ip6 nexthdr tcp ip6 length 40 tcp sport 42834 tcp dport 80 tcp flags == syn tcp window 62587
   trace id 3b90a155 inet nat postrouting rule oifname "ens5" masquerade (verdict accept)
   ```

The traffic is clearly getting to my NAT machine, but it never seems to leave there out to the Internet.

How can I make this work?

Comment: btw in case it wasn't clear: nftables (or Netfilter without jool) offers no such thing. It does NAT, not NAT64

Comment: Please use https://nicmx.github.io/Jool instead of jool.mx